# How to send an email notification about updating the status of the suggestion to its owner?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am developing a web-based suggestions box program for my company where the employees can submit any safety suggestions they have. Now, I am working on the Administration part of this system.

The Admin will be able to see all suggestions listed in a GridView control with the username of the owner. In the last column of the GridView, the status will be listed there. When the Admin clicks on the status of one of these suggestion, a new pop-up window (asp.net ajax ModalPopUpExtender) will be appeared with listing all the possible status such as: actioned, approved... etc. And when the Admin selects one of these status, the status of the suggestion will be updated in the database.
Everything works fine. What I want to do now is when the user updates the status of anyone of the suggestions, an email notfication will be sent to the owner regarding the update of status of his suggestion. **I already wrote the Mail function but I don't know how to get the username of that selected suggestion that its status has been updated. Could anyone help me with this?**

I am really struggling with getting the username of that updated suggestion.

FYI, I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: Username, Name...
SafetySuggestionsLog: ID, Title, Description, Username, StatusID
SafetySuggestionsStatus: ID, Status
```

**ASP.NET code:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" 
                        width="900px" CssClass="mGrid" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" CssClass="alt" />
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold = "True" ForeColor="Black" Height="20px"/> 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                    SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username" 
                    SortExpression="Username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionShortcut" HeaderText="DivisionShortcut" 
                    SortExpression="DivisionShortcut" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />

                <%-- This to make status be opened and edited through the Ajax ModalPopUp Window --%>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkSuggestionStatus" Text='<%#Eval("Status")%>'
                                        OnClick="lnkSuggestionStatus_Click">
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <%--<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Status" 
                    SortExpression="Status" />--%>
            </Columns>
            <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnModalPopUp" style="display:none" />

        <AjaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender ID="modalPopUpExtender1"
                                        runat="server" 
                                        TargetControlID="btnModalPopUp" 
                                        PopupControlID="pnlPopUp" 
                                        BackgroundCssClass="popUpStyle"
                                        PopupDragHandleControlID="panelDragHandle" 
                                        OkControlID="OKButton">
        </AjaxToolkit:ModalPopUpExtender>

        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlPopUp">

                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="StatusList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical"
                                            RepeatLayout="Table" TextAlign="Left" DataSourceID="SuggestionStatusDataSource"
                                            DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="ID">
                        <asp:ListItem id="option1" runat="server" Value="ACTIONED" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option2" runat="server" Value="APPROVED" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option3" runat="server" Value="PENDING" />
                        <asp:ListItem id="option4" runat="server" Value="TRANSFERRED" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SuggestionStatusDataSource" runat="server"
                                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SafetySuggestionsStatus]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

                    <asp:Button ID="confirmButton" runat="server" Text="Confirm" 
                                OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to send an email notification about the safety suggestion to the owner?')" 
                                OnClick="btnSendStatus_Click" />

            <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="Close" />
        </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
protected void lnkSuggestionStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkSuggestionStatus = sender as LinkButton;

        //var safetySuggestionsId = 

        //get reference to the row selected 
        GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)lnkSuggestionStatus.NamingContainer;

        //set the selected index to the selected row so that the selected row will be highlighted
        GridView1.SelectedIndex = gvrow.RowIndex;

        //This HiddenField used to store the value of the ID
        HiddenField1.Value = GridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        //show the modalPopUp
        modalPopUpExtender1.Show();
    }

    public void btnSendStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        var statusID = StatusList.SelectedValue;

        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
        //For updating the status of the safety suggestion
        string updateCommand = "UPDATE SafetySuggestionsLog SET StatusID= @statusID where ID=@SafetySuggestionsID";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statusID", Convert.ToInt32(statusID));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SafetySuggestionsID", Convert.ToInt32(HiddenField1.Value));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            //reset the value of hiddenfield
            HiddenField1.Value = "-1";
        }

        GridView1.DataBind();


        SendSuggestionStatusToUser(statusID);
    }

    protected void SendStatusByEmail(string toAddresses, string fromAddress, string MailSubject, string MessageBody, bool isBodyHtml)
    {
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("MAIL.Aramco.com");
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("pssp@aramco.com", "PMOD Safety Services Portal (PSSP)");

            // In case the mail system doesn't like no to recipients. This could be removed
            //msg.To.Add("pssp@aramco.com");

            msg.Bcc.Add(toAddresses);
            msg.Subject = MailSubject;
            msg.Body = MessageBody;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
            sc.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    protected void SendSuggestionStatusToUser(string status)
    {
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            var sbEmailAddresses = new System.Text.StringBuilder(2000);
            string statusID = status;

            // Open DB connection.
            conn.Open();

            string cmdText2 = "SELECT Username FROM dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText2, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var sName = reader.GetString(0);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sName))
                        {
                            if (sbEmailAddresses.Length != 0)
                            {
                                sbEmailAddresses.Append(",");
                            }
                            // Just use the ordinal position for the user name since there is only 1 column
                            sbEmailAddresses.Append(sName).Append("@aramco.com");
                        }
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            }

            string cmdText3 = "UPDATE dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus SET ID ..........";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText3, conn))
            {
                // Add the parameter to the command
                var oParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("statusID", SqlDbType.Int);

                var sEMailAddresses = sbEmailAddresses.ToString();
                string description = "SELECT Description FROM dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog";
                string body = @"Good day, <br /><br />
                                <b> We just would like to notify you that your following safety suggestion: </b>"
                                    + description +
                                    @"<br /><br />
                            has been.
                            <br /> <br /><br /> <br />
                            This email was generated using the <a href='http://pmv/pssp/Default.aspx'>PMOD Safety Services Portal (PSSP) </a>. 
                            Please do not reply to this email.
                            ";

                int sendCount = 0;
                List<string> addressList = new List<string>(sEMailAddresses.Split(','));
                StringBuilder addressesToSend = new StringBuilder();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(statusID))
                {
                     SendStatusByEmail(addressesToSend.ToString(), "", "Notification of Your Safety Suggestion", body, true);
                     addressesToSend.Clear();
                }

            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Note: I know that I should not post a lengthy code here, but because I want to explain to you my work and to get your help.

Answer (score 1):

Get the user by username from table SafetySuggestionsLog

```
string sqlGetLog = string.format("select * from SafetySuggestionsLog where SafetySuggestionsID= {0}", Convert.ToInt32(HiddenField1.Value));
```

then after you got the SafetySuggestionsLog item/record you take the username and use it to get the user object

```
string userName = SafetySuggestionsLog.UserName; (just get the name from your returned record)

    string sqlGetUser = string.format("select * from Employee where UserName= '{0}'", userName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but honestly I did not get your point. Could you please insert it in my code so I can get the whole picture?

Comment: If i have the time i will try to fix it for you, in the mean time try to refactor your code, you are repeating to much of the same code

Comment: OK. Thanks. I will try and I will let you know if I can fix it.

Comment: DANGER! never use inline sql & values from a form field as above. That's the best way to allow SQL Inject Attacks (what if I changed the value of hiddenfield1 to another suggestion id?). Always use parameters.

Comment: @Johnn Blade, I am still struggling with this. Could you please help me with it?